# How can I use a USB 3.1 Type C (Thunderbolt 3) cable to share internet between two windows 10 devices

Tags: windows-10, connection-sharing, usb-c, usb-3.1-type-c, thunderbolt-networking

Before you say its not possible please update yourself on the specs of this protocol, specifically the section on `10Gb Ethernet connection between computers`:

https://thunderbolttechnology.net/blog/thunderbolt-3-usb-c-does-it-all

---

## Problem

I would like to use a USB-3.1-Type C (Thunderbolt 3) cable as if it was an Ethernet cable.

I need to mount a folder on one computer and share it with the other as a network drive.
Both computers have windows 10 Creators Update on them.

Here is an article explaining that it was possible with Thunderbolt-2 cables:
https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2014/04/intel-expands-10gbps-thunderbolt-ethernet-capability-to-windows/

Comment: Whats special about USB 3.1 Type C cables is they can act as a host-host router. Here is more info about it: https://thunderbolttechnology.net/blog/thunderbolt-3-usb-c-does-it-all

Comment: That like is talking about thunderbolt 3 alternative mode over USB 3.1 type C, rather than generic USB 3.1. While it's possible to configure one side of USB to device mode and do CDC or RNDIS, thunderbolt's solution is more likely doing ethernet over pci-express. So you'll need both sides to support thunderbolt 3 alternative mode on the type C connector, not just any type C. (Type C is just the connector, the signal can vary wildly from USB 2.0 full speed to pci express gen 3).

Answer (score 1):

Not as far as I know. *Thunderbolt 3*, which uses a USB C style connector will do that, and all flavors of thunderbolt have done networking. In *theory* you could probably tell one device to go into 'gadget mode' and one to act as a PC, but I've never seen that, and it needs the hardware explicitly to do so.

> Whats special about USB 3.1 Type C cables is they can act as a host-host router

Is a misconception. *Its just a cable*. There's such a thing called USB Dual role, but I'm not really able to find any mention of it working as networking.

***Not all USB ports are the same***. If its a pair of thunderbolt capable hosts, sure, it'll work. Vanilla USB C is *not* thunderbolt.

If both ends are tbolt3, it should just work with a standard C to C cable. My only tbolt/windows 10 system has a specific bit of software for managing it - tho I've not tested it and "thunderbolt software" is listed as a prerequisite for networking to work on intel's site.

Comment: Ok I might be confused. I saw the section on this site mention it could be used as an ethernet and I got excited: https://thunderbolttechnology.net/blog/thunderbolt-3-usb-c-does-it-all

Comment: thunderbolt tends to 'steal' more common connector types - older generations used mini dp as their connectors. Nearly all those features listed won't work on a regular, non tbolt usb C connector without explicit support (through USB C alternate modes).

Comment: I actually have an iPad pro connected on USB C to my PC (ASUS Maximus Hero X motherboard with USB 3.1 Gen 2). The PC is off now and it charges the iPad. I'm kind of wondering what will happen when the machine boots up. I doubt that there would be any networking capability? iPad can definitely go gigabit with USB C ethernet dongle. Wonder what it would take to configure the PC to share its network in this way. (Reading up on IP over Thunderbolt now)